# Expose information to /proc/iomem

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

As i know, we can see the system memory layout by checking below command result:

```
cat /proc/iomem
```

It will show the physical memory range of system devices:

```
00000000-0000ffff : reserved
00010000-0009f3ff : System RAM
0009f400-0009ffff : reserved
000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000c0000-000c7fff : Video ROM
000ca000-000cbfff : reserved
000ca000-000cafff : Adapter ROM
000cb000-000cbfff : Adapter ROM
000cc000-000cffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000d0000-000d3fff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000d4000-000d7fff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000d8000-000dbfff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000dc000-000fffff : reserved
000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-7fedffff : System RAM
01000000-01520fa4 : Kernel code
01520fa5-01c0e44f : Kernel data
01d56000-0201d963 : Kernel bss
03000000-0b0fffff : Crash kernel
7fee0000-7fefefff : ACPI Tables
7feff000-7fefffff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
7ff00000-7fffffff : System RAM
c0000000-febfffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
fec00000-fec0ffff : reserved
fec00000-fec003ff : IOAPIC 0
fed00000-fed003ff : HPET 0
fed00000-fed003ff : pnp 00:08
fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC
fee00000-fee00fff : reserved
fffe0000-ffffffff : reserved
```

But i am wondering about which code in kernel source will extract and expose these information to /proc/iomem?
Who can let me know?

Thank you ~

Comment: The code located into kernel/resource.c

Comment: @Dmitry, you are right, thanks. 
I have one more question, how does kernel know to map above devices into these memory range?

Comment: Look at [Using I/O Memory](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4)