# How procfs outputs /proc/iomem?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, procfs

I have looked into similar questions on this site (listed at the end) but still feel like missing a couple points, hopefully someone can help here:

1. Is there a hook into the `proc` file system that connects the `/proc/iomem` `inode` to a function that dumps the information? I wasn't able to find where in proc fs this function lives. I did a `grep` under the linux source tree `fs/proc` for `iomem`, got nothing. So maybe it is a more of a `procfs` question... The answer to this question might help me to dig up the answer to the next question..
2. The `/proc/iomem` has more entries than the BIOS E820 information I extracted from either `dmesg` or `/sys/firmware/memmap` (these two are actually consistent with each other). For example, `/sys/firmware/memmap` does not seem to have pci memory mapped regions. Drivers' init code calls the `request_mem_region()` and add more info to the map, so somewhere there should be a global variable (root of all resources ?) that remembers this graph?

The questions on stackoverflow I have looked into:

- [How is /proc/io* populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794633/608639)
- [Expose information to /proc/iomem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39217907/608639)
- [Content of /proc/iomem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583109/608639)

Comment: Looks like it's in `kernel/resource.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `struct resource iomem_resource` is what you're looking for, and it is defined and initialized in `kernel/resource.c` (via `proc_create_seq_data()`). In the same file, the instance `struct seq_operations resource_op` defines what happens when you, for example `cat` the file from userland.
2. `iomem_resource` is a globally exported symbol, and is used throughout the  kernel, drivers included, to request resources. You can find instances scattered across the kernel of `devm_/request_resource()` which take either `iomem_resource` or its sibling `ioport_resource` based on either fixed settings, or based on configurations. Examples of methods that take configurations are a) device trees which is prevalent in embedded settings, and b) E820 or UEFI, which can be found more on x86.

Starting with b) which was asked in the question, the file `arch/x86/kernel/e820.c` shows examples of how reserved memory gets inserted into `/proc/iomem` via `insert_resource()`. 
This excellent [link](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2012/08/uefi-memory-v-e820-memory.html) has more details on the dynamics of requesting memory map details from the BIOS.

Another alternative sequence (which relies on `CONFIG_OF`) for how a device driver requests the needed resources is:

1. The Open Firmware API is traversing the device tree, and finds a matching driver. For example via a `struct of_device_id`.
2. The driver defines a `struct platform_device` which contains both the `struct of_device_id` and a probe function. This probing function is thus called.
3. Inside the probe function, a call to `platform_get_resource()` is made which reads the `reg` property from the device tree. This property defines the physical memory map for a specific device.
4. A call to `devm_request_mem_region()` is made (which is just a call to `request_region()`) to actually allocate the resources and add it to `/proc/iomem`.

Comment: OF is not typical for x86, and, looking at mentioned E820, I think this the case for OP.

Comment: @0andriy OF was meant as an example, this is what I meant by typical. The `iomem_resource` variable -- which is the answer to OP's second question -- applies whether the driver is probed using OF or e820. Anyway I will modify the answer to be less ambiguous.

Comment: thanks guys, this almost cleared all my questions, except this piece - if E820 output does not include PCI mmap region, then that means by the time kernel takes over, pci mmap is still not setup yet? if so, then request_resource() has to have some low level code that sets the hostbridge registers so that future addresses requested by pci devices can be forwarded to pci bridge. But I did not find this code in request_resource().

Comment: (too long, has to split into two replies) Another guess is, BIOS does reserve a huge space for all possible future pci requests, before handing control to kernel, but it just doesn't report it via E820, and kernel somehow dig it out by other means? This way at least request_resource() does not need to tweak hostbridge registers because devices are just requesting for a sub region from within a bigger region, and the bigger region is wholly mapped/forwarded to pci bridge already. Does that remotely make sense?

Comment: @QnA, I'm not sure I fully understand you as I'm not a PCI expert, but wouldn't that fall into a PCI root complex driver responsibilty? From what I understand PCI has a different address space and you may have an endpoint hotplugged at any time. I'm confident the registers for the root complex are somewhat reserved using the mentioned mechanisms and subsequently configured , but for the actual memory used depends on the driver. My untested guess is that an endpoint would initiate enumeration according to PCI protocol, which triggers an ISR, then RC would start reserving memory for endpoint.

Comment: @QnA My continued response, as I ran out of chars. The way RC would reserve memory would (I think) be using the the DMA kernel API, rather than the request region(). Anyway I think PCI deserves its own question, otherwise you may want to rename the question title to "How procfs outputs /proc/iomem for PCI?"

Comment: @QnA, PCI is **self-discovery** bus, and what you are talking about is hidden under *drivers/pci/setup-res.c*. Also for PCI-ACPI based platforms the information is propagated via MCFG table according to PCI Firmware specification.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. ACPI seems to be the answer for PCI memory forwarding setup at hostbridge level, Documentation/PCI/acpi-info.rst.